# Trac plugin development: How to get access to trac.ini item from plugin

Tags: python, plugins, trac

I have created a plugin which is working perfectly fine!

Now I need to get access to some value in trac.ini from that plugin

The plugin is implementing `ITemplateStreamFilter`

the method is `def filter_stream(self, req, method, filename, stream, data):`

How can I get value for some `key` in trac.ini from that method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use Configuration class for this purpose [config.py](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/trunk/trac/config.py) there implement get method:

```
 def get(self, section, key, default=''):
     return self[section].get(key, default)
```

where section is section name in config file, and key is option.

Comment: This helped me http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/ConfigApi I have used self.env.config.get('section', 'value') Thanks!

Comment: it's just an article to the class of which I have given above

Comment: In filter_stream I have used "self.env.config.get" and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Be sure to check for other available class methods, like *.getbool()* or *.getint()* depending on the option type to simplify your own code.